# Why are you giving the error %dopar% not found even after loading the foreach package?

Tags: r

I want to generate clusters from a multivariate dataset in locations in the (x, y) plane, in two steps. In the first step (already executed) I used a more dense set of data and separated in previous classes. In the second stage of clustering I want to use this prior information to refine and create the final cluster. They are soil and plant data of an agricultural area. I am not able to execute the second step, and tried to use the "foreach" and "doParallel" R packages, without success. R reports that the% dopar% function was not found. First, I ran a code, with several "for" strings. The process was extremely slow. I interrupted. I saw that it was possible to use parallel computing, but I do not have this knowledge. I installed the "foreach" and "doParallel" packages. Just with "foreach" I can execute small parts of the code and verify that it is actually working. But when I enter% dopar% after the "foreach" parameter, R reports the error of not finding this function.

## #The last column of the data set (p+1) indicates the a priori classes.

```
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
require(geoR)
```

### #Product of the differences between variables

```
Z<-function(dados,var,ponto1,ponto2){
    return(as.numeric(dados$data[ponto1,var]-dados$data[ponto2,var]))
}
```

## Kernel estimator with priori information

```
Klambda<-function(dados,ponto1,ponto2){
    dmatriz<-as.matrix(dist(dados$coords))
    if(dmatriz[ponto1,ponto2]>=2.23){return(0)}
    if(dados$data[ponto1,p+1]!=dados$data[ponto2,p+1]){return(0.2*(0.75*(2.23^2-dmatriz[ponto1,ponto2]^2))}
    if(dados$data[ponto1,p+1]==dados$data[ponto2,p+1]){return(0.8*(0.75*(2.23^2-dmatriz[ponto1,ponto2]^2))}
}
```

## Numerator

```
Numerador<-function(dados,ponto1,ponto2,var1,var2){
    result=0
    foreach(k=1:n)%dopar%{
        kl = Klambda(dados,ponto1,k)
        foreach(l=1:n)%dopar%{
            result=result+(kl *Klambda(dados,ponto2,l)*Z(dados,var1,k,l)*Z(dados,var2,k,l))
    }
}
return(result)
```

}

## Denominator

```
Denominador<-function(dados,ponto1,ponto2){
    n=nrow(dados$data)
    result=0
    foreach(k=1:n)%dopar%{
        foreach(l=1:n)%dopar%{
            result=result+(Klambda(dados,ponto1,k)*Klambda(dados,ponto2,l))
        }
    }
    return(2*result)
}
```

### #Gamma: direct and cross semivariance

```
GammaHat<-function(dados,ponto1,ponto2,var1,var2){return(Numerador(dados,ponto1,ponto2,var1,var2)/Denominador(dados,ponto1,ponto2))
}
```

## Dissimilarity

```
Dlambda<-function(dados,ponto1,ponto2){
    result=0
    foreach(i=1:p)%dopar%{
        foreach(j=1:p)%dopar%{
            result=result+GammaHat(dados,ponto1,ponto2,i,j)
        }
    }
    return(result)  
}
```

## Matrix of dissimilarity

```
MatrizD<-array(dim=c(n,n))
system.time(
    foreach(k=1:n)%dopar%{
        foreach(l=1:n)%dopar%{
        if(l<=k){
            MatrizD[k,l]<- Dlambda(d,k,l)
        }
        MatrizD[l,k]<-MatrizD[k,l]
    }
}
)
```

## For the test file (12 locations, 3 variables plus the a priori class), without the foreach the code for the dissimilarity matrix takes around 100 seconds. However, I could not execute yet for the actual data set (102 points, 23 variables plus the a priori class).

x   y   var1    var2    var3    Class
1   1   0.245   0.514   0.048   1
1   2   0.825   0.427   0.100   1
1   3   0.873   0.803   0.452   1
2   1   0.452   0.801   0.510   1
2   2   0.243   0.855   0.303   1
2   3   0.640   0.108   0.954   1
3   1   0.834   0.185   0.418   1
3   2   0.998   0.160   0.787   2
3   3   0.596   0.030   0.840   2
4   1   0.506   0.264   0.503   2
4   2   0.975   0.441   0.011   2
4   3   0.466   0.138   0.482   2

Comment: First of all, `foreach` is not equivalent to `for`. You can't use the same syntax and in particular no side effects like assigning into `MatrizD` for parrallel computing. Study the package vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf Then, this is not how you nest `foreach`. You should study the relevant `foreach` package vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf However, usually it is better to only parallelize the outer loop.

Comment: Greetings, Roland!  Thank you for the feedback. My question is based on how can I speed up the calculations in this function? See that all calculations are dependent on each other, and it's taking up too much code processing time.

Comment: If your calculations depend on each other, you cannot use parallelization.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of what I could do in this case to optimize the code? Or rewrite otherwise? Thanks.